# Modifying and comparing nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```
for mov_id in user_ratings:
    for id_key in mov_id:
```

the loop was not working

Comment: Your `if` condition looks like a typo. I bet you get an error from modifying while iterating. But unless you explain what's actually wrong, and show a complete runnable example, it's very difficult to answer this question.

Comment: yes that is one of the mistakes i do get. sorry i am a newbie here. what can i do to fix this

Comment: Use the edit button under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should pop `id_key` from the dict you iterate the keys through instead, which is `mov_id`.

Change:

```
user_ratings.pop(id_key)
```

to:

```
mov_id.pop(id_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative.

```
user_ratings = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
mov_id = {'z': 260, 'd': -12, 'r': 1, 'b': 0}
result = {k: v for k, v in user_ratings.items() if k not in mov_id}
print(result)
```

Comment: I think your condition is backwards. Should be `if k in mov_id`